# Dominant term of $f(x)=\frac{a}{a+ax+(1-a)\sqrt{x}}$, where $0\le a \le 1$, $x>0$ when $x\to 0$

Tags: asymptotics

If I have a function $$f(x)=\frac{a}{a+ax+(1-a)\sqrt{x}}$$ where $0\le a \le1$, $x>0$. Then, what's the dominant term in denominator when $x\to 0$?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=1$.

Comment: @Rohan What happens if $a=0$?

Comment: In case it's not clear: Aside from the particular case when $a=0$, Rohan's comment gives the correct dominant term of $f(x)$. The dominant term in the denominator is clearly $a$ when $a > 0$ because everything else goes to $0$.